# Tool to set the maximum shape area of drawn polygons [ArcGIS 10]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon-creation

Is there any tool or method to define beforehand the maximum area of each drawn polygon class ? Polygons are going to be distributed according to my idea so I need to have control over the process. I can imagine it the way that while drawing polygons I am not able to exceed the previously defined threshold value.

I started doing it manually (had to create patches of tree species of exact total size in ha) and was checking the total size in a table of attributes but I believe there is a way to do it in more comfortable and precise way.

Comment: Do the polygons have specific (regular) shapes or irregular shapes?

Comment: I would like to create irregularly shaped polygons and also many in the same class (for example 10 patches of various size and shape representing oak trees, in total of 20% area of the plot.

Answer (score 1):

If the polygons a have regular shapes like square of rectangle, you can go (in ArcGIS) to `Start Editing -> Select the new feature to draw -> then use the right-click context menu to gain access to the "length" tool when creating a new feature`. You can specify the fixed length that you want. If the polygons are of irregular shape, you can follow the same process, but you need to specify the angle when drawing.